# Windows10 Oracle ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: oracle

I use sqlplus to connect my windows 10 oracle sql server, if I use `sqlplus system` and enter the password, everything works just fine, but if I use `sqlplus system/test@192.168.8.4:1521/orcl`, the error occur `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`. I have also tried to use oracle sql developer

[image]

But another error occur.

here is my listener.ora

```
# This is a sample listener.ora that contains the NET8 parameters that are
# needed to connect to an HS Agent

LISTENER =
 (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))
 )

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
      (SID_DESC=
         (SID_NAME=dg4odbc)
         (ORACLE_HOME=C:\Users\test\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
         (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
      )
  )


#dg4odbc
#CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER = 0
```

here is my tnsnames.ora

```
# This is a sample tnsnames.ora that contains the NET8 parameters that are
# needed to connect to an HS Agent

dg4odbc  =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dg4odbc))
    (HS=OK)
  ) 

#dg4odbc
```

I have tried to change all dg4odbc to orcl, but seem like not working

select instance from v$thread

```
INSTANCE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
orcl
```

Comment: Where are you finding that tnsnames.ora and listener.ora?  Are you trying to create a database link to a non-Oracle database?  The files you posted would be used for configuring Heterogeneous Services which is what you'd use to create a database link to a non-Oracle database.  I don't think those are the files you want to be referencing.  I'm assuming the Oracle database is installed locally (i.e. the 8.4 IP address is the IP address of your client and of the database server).  If you open Oracle Net Manager, do you see anything under Listeners in the tree control?  I'm guessing not.